# Is the sentence “The table is included for completeness” correct?

Tags: writing-style

I've used the sentence “The table is included for completeness” several times in university reports and have seen it in reports of other students as well. 
I am wondering if this sentence is correct though, as I can only find [very](https://www.google.nl/search?client=firefox-a&hs=hkl&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=fflb&q=%22The+table+is+included+for+completeness%22&oq=%22The+table+is+included+for+completeness%22&gs_l=serp.3...2918.4261.0.4451.2.2.0.0.0.0.97.159.2.2.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..2.0.0.HC65hFihbuc) [little](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+table+is+included+for+completeness%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) occurrences of this sentence in Google (Books).

Are there any other, more elegant alternatives to express that I include something (a table, an appendix, an image from a different angle, etc...) that clarifies the content, but the addition is not necessary ( without it the content is understandable).

Comment: It doesn't sound correct. What kind of "table" is it? Is this a reference? "The table of logarithms is marked Fig. 1"; Is it a [literal table](http://theodoregray.com/periodictable/)?

Comment: In this example it's a table containing values which are also visualised in a figure. The table shows the data quantitatively, the figure qualitatively, although the figure does contain a legend with values. However, this is just an example, I'm more interested in the general sentence that can be used in the situation where you include something (a table, an appendix, an additional column in a table, etc...) that a casual reader could do without, but might come in handy for someone who is using the report for in-depth research.

Comment: I would just use "See the table below" at an appropriate point to avoid implying that the article would be incomplete without it. Although since you **are** including it, I'm not sure why you need to defend yourself from this charge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as there is context to it (i.e. a table) then it makes sense. It is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3):

"Included for completeness" is a common expression, in the sense you describe, especially in scientific writing. There are currently around 90,000 book results for "[included for completeness](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22included+for+completeness%22&tbm=bks)".